# Get slideToggle() to reveal content directly above it, as opposed to below it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

---

**Problem summary: Instead of doing what the code currently usually does - revealing content beneath the button - I need it to reveal content *above* it.**

---

First of all I'm not versed in jQuery/Javascript in any sense, so if I'm asking for too much to be done on my behalf then please say so and hint toward the solution.

Now, onto the problem:

```
$('.drop_down_title').click(function() {
     $(this).next('.toggle_panel').slideToggle('slow', function () { });
     $(this).find('.arrow_drop_down').toggleClass('selected', function () { });
});
```

The code above is working fantastic to show content below a title (like having various 'related' blocks in the sidebar that you can hide/show).

However I've also planned to use the same mechanic for hiding portions of content that would be above the button, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B91DC.png

Where the buttons would be clicked to reveal more of the summary or bullet points.

I've tried tweaking the code to things that seem logical like:

```
$(this).previous('.toggle_panel')
```

In hope of it looking up the page for the relevant class, but still no dice.

Thank you for your time; any advice, help or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Requested HTML (for the current working slide **down**):

```
<html>

<div class="slidebox">

    <div class="drop_down_title">
        <a class="arrow_drop_down">Button Click</a>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle_panel">
        <p>This is some example content that should be hidden when the above button is clicked!</p>
    </div>

</div>
</html>
```

**I'm trying to get it so that the divs "drop_down_title" and "toggle_panel" are swapped. So that the content is being revealed above the button.**

Comment: could you show some html, please?

Comment: If you position the element absolutely based on it's bottom, slideToggle will animate the elements height, and therefore it will animate top down rather than bottom up. Though, i doubt that's really what you need to do. we need to see some html/css

Comment: @Tetaxa Added the HTML, I hope that helps!

Comment: @KevinB I can't absolute position the elements. I need them to be blocks in the normal flow.

I'm not sure how CSS will help though. No css bar standard styling has been needed to get the drop-down one working, thus there's nothing really to post. Popped the HTML in though.

Comment: So... When you click more, the content sectino above the button needs to grow in height? If that's the case it would have made sense to show two sections in your html sample, because as it is now we have to target a theoretical element that you haven't shown us. In either case, some combination of `.closest(selector).prev().find(selector)` should do what you want.

Comment: @KevinB Instead of what it usually does - reveal content beneath the button - I need it to reveal content above it. Hope that's clearer!

Comment: @OkamiStudio That isn't clear though. The html you have given us doesn't have any content above the button. Is the previous panel in the same slide-box? a separate slide-box? etc

Comment: I know, I tried to clearly say that this is what's currently working for the slide_down_. Swap the 'toggle_panel' div with the 'drop_down_title' div to get what I want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps .prev() is what you actually need. Not .previous. See [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: Tried simply putting prev in place of previous which didn't work. To be honest I think this may just be down to my lack of understanding in Javascript and jQuery. I can't imagine it should be heard to reveal content above a button, rather than below it.

I'll get to reading up on the basics of them both in the meantime, thank you for the suggestion and link.

Comment: Why can't you position .toggle_panel above .drop_down_title and use .prev()? If you really need to move the divs then you can use `$(this).next().insertBefore($(this)).slideToggle('slow', function () { });`

Comment: Aha! I saw you just commented as I was about to write this, and with the problem as well! It was my understanding/knowledge that was the issue, I read the documentation and realized that it's not used for targetting a selector, but rather the previous sibling (which you're right, is perfect for me!). So all I had to do was remove the selector (leaving me with prev()) and et voila, it worked! Thank you very much!